# Having selected values in a multi select in IE

Tags: javascript, select

Hello I have a multiselect box, whose answers would be available already. Now when a page loads, this select multiple control would load with options, and I have to compare all the options to this answer/answers and display them as selected. It is working fine in FF but not in IE.

`var op = newSelectorElm.options;
    if(op)
    for(var j=0; j< op.length;j++)
    {
        if(z instanceof Array)
        {
            if(in_array(op[j].value, z))
            {

            op[j].selected=true;
    //      objOption.defaultSelected = true;
}`

`}   }`

I tried to alert if it was going into the if loop, everything works. Displaying a visual indication that it is preselect alone is the problem.

in_array is a custom function in our javascript framework and works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `op[j].setAttribute("selected", "selected");`.